# Training the classfication model with the timestamp

Tags: machine-learning, timestamp, time-series, classification

I have a theoretical question. I have a time series dataset (containing two feature columns: timestamp and temperature) and I want to use it for a binary classification problem by applying some machine learning logarithms (KNN,Random Forest, SVM and naive bayes) using Python. My question is:

Would it possible to train the model with the timestamp feature or would it cause some learning issues such as over-fitting?

I was wondering if you guys have any theoretical recommendation whether is it effective to train the model with or without the timestamp or what is the best practice in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **timestamp** is an encoded value so, the column usually has a too much variations for the most of the examples you have, as it's usually collected **per second** which entirely changes the encoded value.

---

### Recommendation

Convert **timestamp** to **UTC-time** and discretize its values by some threshold (**seconds**, **minutes**, .. Etc.), may try **k-means** **discretization**, another **poor** approach, is to check the number of unique values in this column (**timestamp feature**) if it's **too small** or **too large**, then it's going to be useless for most of the **algorithm** and might be too much hurtful for some collection of algorithms.

---

The values which aren't contributing at **forecasting** tasks, might hurt **trees algorithms**, and case **overfitting** even using **Random Forest** not going to be too much helpful, and it's also **hurting algorithms**, which **formulated** by **unconstrained** problems such **logistic regression** (without regularization **constraint**). For algorithms such **SVM**, despite, it's a **constrained** problem, and its **performance** might not be changed by using **useless feature**, but the problem is, the data might be not **separable** enough which might lead to extremely poor model (**underfitting**).

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation, I just wonder, does this recommendation apply also to the classification problem. I mentioned that the values might not be useful for foresting tasks, how about the classification.

Comment: You are welcome, Yeah, it's the same problem, this doesn't make any difference

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.